# Jupyter Notebook encoding error?

Tags: python, encoding, jupyter-notebook

I started to learn pandas by following this tutorial:

https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook

Right in the first chapter I try very elementary example of reading a csv file. The example goes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
broken_df = pd.read_csv("..\data\bikes.csv")
```

I get a lengthy error message, which ends with a line:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'..\\data\x08ikes.csv' does not exist
```

So although I write 'bikes.csv', which I have in the correct folder, the program seems to be searching for a file called 'x08ikes.csv'. Could this be an encoding error? sys.getdefaultencoding() returns 'utf-8'.

I am using Anaconda3 for 64bit Windows, version 4.4.0. My browser is Brave. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Try to use full path instead of `..\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash character `'\'` has special meaning; it tries to "escape" the next character.  In this case `'\b'` is an escape character that does have a meaning.  There are three ways around this:

#### Escape the escapes:

You can use the backslash to escape the next backslash, telling Python "this is just another character"

```
broken_df = pd.read_csv("..\\data\\bikes.csv")
```

#### Use a raw string:

Placing `r` at the beginning of a string tells Python to interpret everything in the string as-is

```
broken_df = pd.read_csv(r"..\data\bikes.csv")
```

#### Use forward slashes:

This is specific to file paths.  You can trace the directory to you file using forward slashes instead of backslashes.

```
broken_df = pd.read_csv("../data/bikes.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately none of those did work. They all return this error message: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 15: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: That is a different error which indicates that the file was reachable, but it could not be read properly using the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. Next I need to find out what is the encoding of that file.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, upload the `bikes.csv` in to the Jupyter Home "Files" tab. Open it and you may still see the message. Then go to File->New, and you may get a new blank file. Open the original `bikes.csv` in notepad, copy and paste the content in to the file in jupyter notebook. This may help to resolve it.

Then you can run the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
broken_df = pd.read_csv("..\data\bikes.csv")
```